# How to add multiple terms to a taxonomy reference field via feeds?

Tags: 7, feeds

I would like to import a node with multiple taxonomy terms referenced in one of node fields.
How can I do this with Feeds and Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) module to "explode" the comma-delimited list of taxonomy terms into individual references.

> Feeds Tamper provides a small plugin architecture for Feeds to modify data before it gets saved. Several plugins are available by default and are described in the examples section below.
>   Additional plugins can be added in separate modules or through the issue queue.

Comment: In my situation, the list is not a comma separated list. It is like

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the list is not a comma separated list. It is as follows:

```
<product>
    <category>Ship</category>
    <id>000032</id>
    <Description>The description comes here</Description>
    <list>
        <Destination>
            <DestinationName>Dest 1</DestinationName>
            <DestinationCountryISOAlpha3>US</DestinationCountryISOAlpha3>
        </Destination>
        <Destination>
            <DestinationName>Dest 2</DestinationName>
            <DestinationCountryISOAlpha3/>
        </Destination>
    <list>
</product>
```

I have a taxonomy called destinations and the list is already imported. Now how can I import Destinations list of a product as a term reference for the product node. I am using feed module, Feeds XPath Parser, and Feeds Tamper modules?

Answer (score -2):

I'd like to suggest the [Manage Multiple Terms](https://drupal.org/project/manage_multiple_terms) module.

> Manage Multiple Terms provides a simple mechanism to add, update, delete many terms in the same time easily and quickly.